# definir LIMIT na paginação de resultados

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com um problema tenho uma base de dados que uso para teste onde tem 1000 registro e tenho um site que puxa esses dados para serem apresentados. Estou usando a paginação na minha query esta desta maneira

```
$read->FullRead("SELECT * FROM teste LIMIT $p , $qt_por_pg");
```

No arquivo php tem as seguintes variáveis

```
$p = $_GET['p']; 

$qt_por_pg = 20;
```

Recebo via `GET` o numero da pagina. E defini que quero 20 resultados por pagina o sistema esta todo funcionando exceto por um detalhe onde ele puxa os 1000 resultados so que que quero definir um limite de 100 resultados e não 1000 como já uso o LIMIT para fazer a paginação como poderia definir esse limite.

Comment: O `LIMIT` só lhe obtem a quantidade de registos indicados pelo `offset` que é o valor a seguir a virgula, logo no seu caso apenas 20. Agora se `$p` indica a página você quer apenas começar no primeiro registo dessa página que é `$p*$qt_por_pg`

Comment: para que possa entender na base de dados tem 1000 registros usando o LIMIT 1 , 20 ele irar pegar do registro 1 ate o 20 certo e se eu passar o valor LIMIT 2 , 20 ele irar pegar do registro 2 ate e anda mais 20 e assim por diante ate chegar aos mil certo so que quero definir um limite maximo de 100 registro e não mil algo como LIMIT $p , $qt_por_pg LIMIT 100

Comment: Isso não existe. Cada select é uma consulta em separado. Logo cada consulta trás apenas 20 registos, e regra geral é o que faz sentido pois normalmente apenas obtem uma página de cada vez à medida que o usuário navega nelas. Se quer obter logo várias páginas tem fazer uma consulta que obtenha logo os 100 registos e paginar "manualmente"

Comment: Mysql já aceita offset aproveita a sintaxe completa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cláusula **LIMIT** é utilizada para limitar o número de resultados de uma SQL. Então, se sua SQL retornar 1000 linhas, mas você quer apenas as 20 primeiras, você deve executar uma instrução assim:

```
SELECT coluna FROM tabela LIMIT 20;
```

Agora, vamos supor que você quer somente os resultados de 11 a 20. Com a instrução **OFFSET** fica fácil, basta proceder da seguinte forma:

```
 SELECT coluna FROM tabela LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10;
```

O comando OFFSET indica o início da leitura, e o LIMIT o máximo de registros a serem lidos. Para os registros de 61 a 75, por exemplo:

```
 SELECT coluna FROM tabela LIMIT 15 OFFSET 60;
```

Com este recurso, fica fácil paginar os resultados de uma **SQL** e mostrar ao usuário apenas a página, ao invés de retornar todos os registros da tabela. Uma tabela com 1000 registros, por exemplo, fica muito melhor mostrar ao usuário de 20 em 120, por exemplo, e diminui a carga no banco de dados, melhorando a sua performance.

Referência: [Hallan Medeiros Blog](http://blog.hallanmedeiros.com/2011/11/23/sql-paginando-resultados-com-limit-e-offset/)